# Logcheck not sending email

Tags: email, log

I just installed logcheck, modified its config to my email address, but when i prompt a test run i dont get the email. If i redirect the output to STDOUT i get the correct infos.

I read somewhere that i need to set up an email client for it which sounds something i am missing, as i did not do it. I could not find any related simple information about how to do it.

Do i really need to install some kind of email server? If yes what is an easy solution and how can i make it work with logcheck? Also if logcheck is unable to send a mail why dont i get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Well it lists `fetchmail` as a dependency in apt-cache so it should send the mail without any other mail server. How did you install it? If it was through apt-get it should already have fetchmail installed.

Try installing it with `sudo apt-get install fetchmail` or reinstall logcheck with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall logcheck`

Comment: I installed it via apt-get, and i do have the fetchmail.